# jQuery html() memory problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

when doing the following i can watch the memory usage just soar in the task manager in chrome.  i don't get it.  if i comment out one line ($("#main_table tbody").html(string);) then all is fine in the world.  any thoughts?  thanks everyone.  oh this is run once per second in a "setTimeout" loop thats how i am seeing the memory climb higher as its doing it once per second.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>includes/updateTable.php',
    cache: false,
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data)
    {
      var string = '';

      $.each(data.monitorData, function(i,monitor)
      {
        string = string + '<tr id="r'+monitor['id']+'">';

        for (var key in monitor)
        {
          string = string + '<td>'+monitor[key]+'</td>';
        }
        string = string + '</tr>';
      });

      $("#main_table tbody").html(string);
    }
  });
```

Comment: How many `monitorData`  are we talking about here? A dozen? A hundred? A thousand?

Comment: You could try $("#main_table tbody")[0].innerHTML = string; to see if that helps.

Comment: @user , use firebug and console.log the monitor[key] and what it has and why the memory is jumping up, sometimes string concatination run into memory issues.

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the table elsewhere in the javascript? If you are hooking events directly to elements inside the table, or referencing the dom elements in any way, you may be retaining references to them thus they are being retained in memory.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding

```
$("#main_table tbody").empty();
```

right before

```
$("#main_table tbody").html(string);
```

It technically shouldn't make a difference but....

Comment: @Pekka 280 rows in the table and 16 cells so 4480 fields i guess.  memory usage grows at about 1MB per second in chrome.  i tried just now doing the whole array thing and pushing each part to it and doing this for the table $("#main_table tbody")[0].innerHTML = string.join(""); it is still growing the same

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that since the string var is used in the lambda function (in $.each), javascript is not garbage collecting it.

Try adding:

```
delete string
```

to the end of the success function.

Comment: This might not work depending on whether or not `string` can be seen as a property of an object.